# sending Apple event to console application

Tags: applescript, appleevents

I have console app named "MyApp" it is running and I see it in the activity monitor.

I'm writing in AppleScript Editor the script:

```
tell application "MyApp"

display dialog "Hello World"

end tell
```

When running the script the editor asks me where is MyApp? And it doesn't appear in the list it shows. When I'm trying to brows it's location, I can't select MyApp's bundle.
How can I deal with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to addressing the bundle identifier and not the application name.

```
tell application id "com.MyApp.app"
    display dialog "Hello World"
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `NSAppleScriptEnabled` to `Info.plist`. The entry looks like:

```
<key>NSAppleScriptEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

You can find this entry in all scriptable apps, such as:

```
open /Applications/Preview.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

Because it's manually added, you might need to re-add the code if you recompile the app.